# Solidity event not showing up from Web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, contract-design, events

I'm trying to set up an event in `Solidity` and listen to it from `Web3` but I keep getting a `null` response. Here's my code:

The relevant part of the contract:

```
event NewUser(string userid);

function createNewUser(string memory _userId) public {
    // creating the user and setting it to a mapping 
    emit NewUser(_userId);
}
```

The `Javascript`, from `Ethereum's` reference:

```
async function watchEvents(contract) {
    contract.events.allEvents({
       fromBlock: 0
    },function(error, event){ console.log('all events?'); console.log(event); })
  .on('data', function(event){
     console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
  })
  .on('changed', function(event){
     // remove event from local database
  })
  .on('error', console.error);
}
```

Using another `javascript` function I can see that new users are being created, and the transactions are listed as successful on `Ganache`. But the `watchEvents` method keeps printing `null`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using websocket provider? Http provider does not support events

Comment: @SanjaySB Not even for listing past data?? Anyway no, I didn't know that. Do you know how do I specify `websockets` in `truffle` and point it to `ganache`? If you write it as an answer and it works it'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out web sockets by adding the following in `truffle-config.js` file.

```js
networks: {
 development: {
      provider: function() {
        return new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:7545");
      },
      network_id: "5777"
    }
...
}
```

You will have to import Web3.